# Makefile rule is never up-to-date

Tags: makefile

(Yes, I know this question gets asked a lot. I think this case is different.)

Makefile:

```
dependency := ./dependency
target_file := ./target

.PHONY: target
target: $(target_file)

$(dependency):
    touch $@

$(target_file): $(dependency)
    touch $@
```

Running `make --trace` once yields this output:

```
Makefile:8: target 'dependency' does not exist
touch dependency
make: Circular target <- target dependency dropped.
Makefile:11: update target 'target' due to: dependency
touch target
```

That's pretty much as expected, although the circular target bit is odd.

Subsequent invocations of the `make --trace` yield this output:

```
make: Circular target <- target dependency dropped.
Makefile:11: update target 'target' due to: dependency
touch target
```

There's still that circular target, and it recreates the target file even though it was already up-to-date. It also claims the dependency file was out of date, but it *doesn't* recreate that.

What is causing this behavior? One possible clue: if you replace `./target` with `./foo` it behaves as you'd expect.

Comment: It's considering `./target` to be the same as `target`  (they resolve to the same file after all...)   So `target : ./target` would cause a circular dependency...   Also `.PHONY : target` is going to cause `./target` to rebuild

Comment: The "due to: dependency" is an error in the trace output.  That error has been fixed for the next release.  It should say "due to: phony" or something like that.

Comment: To emphasize what @hardcorehenry said: by declaring `.PHONY: target`, you have *explicitly* asked Make to always rebuild that target. It's doing exactly what you want! You can read more about phony targets [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: Variables in makefiles are just strings, though, and "`./target`" is most definitely not the same as "`target`".

Comment: GNU make has a special exemption that treats `./foo` and `foo` (as prerequisites and targets) as the same thing, because they are the same thing (as files).  I thought it was mentioned in the manual but all I see is this in the "features" section: _Strip leading sequences of ‘./’ from file names, so that `./file` and `file` are considered to be the same file._ which isn't really sufficient from a documentation standpoint.  This is a trivial conversion and easily fooled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally for `make`, and generally speaking for GNU `make`, target and prerequisite names are flat strings, in that `make` does not know about directories or paths, and it does not attempt to canonicalize target names as paths or any such thing.

**Except**, GNU `make` *does* provide special handling in the particular case of leading sequences of `./` in target and prerequisite names.  Per [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Features), such sequences are stripped, with the effect that `./file` and `file` are equivalent as target and / or prerequisite names to this `make` implementation.  That's apparently a GNU invention, and it is the source of the odd behavior you observe.

Safest, especially if you want portability to other `make`s, is to avoid target and prerequisite names starting with `./`.